# How can I call a Jquery method on DOM elements that don't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, facebox

I'd like to use [this lightbox plugin](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) for some autocomplete links, that don't yet exist on my page.

You normally activate it using:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

Since the a links aren't all on the page upon page load, I would normally look to the `.live` or `.delegate` methods to bind to an event, but in this case, what 'event' would I bind to to say "once this element is on the page, then call this method on it".

Or am I going about this totally the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event.

You need to invoke the plugin when you add the elements to the page.

```
   // create a new <a>, append it, and call the plugin against it.
$('<a>',{rel:"facebox"}).appendTo('body').facebox();
```

This example creates a new `<a>` element. If you're getting some elements from an AJAX response, call it against those:

```
var elems = $( response );

elems.filter( 'a[rel="facebox"]' ).facebox(); // if the <a> is at the top level
elems.find( 'a[rel="facebox"]' ).facebox();   // if the <a> is nested

elems.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!   I was hoping there was a way around this, but I guess not

Comment: @Noli: You're welcome. There is a plugin called `livequery` that monitors the DOM for changes, but as I understand it is pretty resource hungry. You'll be better off doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet tested :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).bind('change', docChanged) ;
})

function docChanged()
{
    if ($('a[rel*=facebox][class!="faceboxed"]').length > 0)
    {
        $('a[rel*=facebox][class!="faceboxed"]').addClass("faceboxed").facebox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really !? I was a bit doubting with the event _change_ with document but if you say that it is working, I'm happy for you !

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea that even existed.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: About resources, you can check change in a particular elem in document because it could be huge work for browser...

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely possible using the .live function. You just need to use the DOMNodeInserted event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel*=facebox]").live("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
        $(this).facebox();
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks good.. but i'm having trouble getting it to work on Chrome..   not sure if there's a Chrome/Jquery problem or what..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to just add this call to the ajax that loads in the links.